# mysql select from table if row exists otherwise select from a different table

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables, and I want to select from tablea if the row exists but if none does exist then I want to select a row from tableb (if it exists in that) otherwise if it exists in none it returns null.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE users.domainid = :domainid AND users.user = :user LIMIT :limit) > 0 
THEN (SELECT id,receiving,greylistingdisable FROM users WHERE users.domainid = :domainid AND users.user = :user LIMIT :limit) 
ELSE (SELECT id,blockexpires,recordexpires FROM auto_deny WHERE auto_deny.domainid = :domainid AND auto_deny.user = :user AND auto_deny.blockexpires >= :blockexpires LIMIT :limit)
END
```

I have tried so may different combination of things but I can never get it to work. This one seems the closest I have gotten tho but it returns an error:

> "ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: You may have to join the two tables together.  That being said, how can `users` be joinded to `auto_deny` ?

Comment: but can you join if a users row doesn't even exist?  the user column in both would be the same value to match

Comment: You are almost there using `CASE`.  But the trick is that you will show _all_ columns in the result set, but you will selectively blank out columns from the table you _don't_ want to show.

Comment: Do you want a `UNION` of the two tables, or separate columns from both tables in each record?

Comment: seperate would be best, so i know from which table the results came from

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the queries themselves are working properly and you just the conditional selection to work as you describe I would try using `exists` and `not exists` subqueries on each side and connecting them with a union. One should return rows and the other not, as appropriate, achieving what you want in the end.

```
(   select  id,
            receiving,
            greylistingdisable,
            'x' as src -- to distinguish rows as being sourced from x or y
    from    users
    where   users.domainid = :domainid
        and exists ( select  1
                     from    users
                     where   users.domainid = :domainid
                         and users.user = :user )
        and users.user = :user
    limit :limit
)
union all
(   select  id,
            blockexpires,
            recordexpires,
            'y'
    from    auto_deny
    where   auto_deny.domainid = :domainid
        and auto_deny.user = :user
        and not exists ( select  1
                         from    users
                         where   users.domainid = :domainid
                             and users.user = :user )
        and auto_deny.blockexpires >= :blockexpires
    limit :limit
)
```

Comment: the combining into one result doesn't work as the column names don't match if the result is not found in users but is found in auto_deny. The column names = that of the users table which wont tell me where the results came from.

Comment: you can select a literal in each, like 'x' and 'y' (see edit) to distinguish from which query the result was returned. As for the column names, depending on how important they are, you could select them as literals also. They would become a part of the data, and the actual column names would need to be disregarded, but may be enough depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a prioritization query using `union all`:

```
(SELECT id, receiving, greylistingdisable, 1 as isuser
 FROM users u
 WHERE u.domainid = :domainid AND u.user = :user
 LIMIT :limit
) UNION ALL
(SELECT id, blockexpires, recordexpires, 0 as isuser
 FROM auto_deny ad
 WHERE ad.domainid = :domainid AND ad.user = :user AND 
       ad.blockexpires >= :blockexpires AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE u.domainid = :domainid and u.user = :user)
 LIMIT :limit
)
```

Note:  The use of `limit` without an `order by` is considered bad practice.  You should usually include an `order by` to guarantee that the query returns the same results each time it is called.